# Kubernetes logging

Tags: logging, kubernetes, scaling, stackdriver

I recently upgraded my cluster and I am continuously seeing these kinds of errors:

```
Error from server (NotFound): scalingpolicies.scalingpolicy.kope.io "fluentd-gcp-scaling-policy" not found    
E 
2018-11-30T19:00:20,400581557+00:00 fluentd-gcp-scaling-policy not found in namespace kube-system, using defaults.
I 
Error from server (NotFound): daemonsets.extensions "fluentd-gcp-v3.0.0" not found
E
```

I think the problem is that my fluentd has a different version, but I am not sure how to change this in the scaling policy

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your `ScalingPolicy` CRD with the name `fluentd-gcp-scaling-policy` is missing. It would be that something changed in the CRD when you did the upgrade too.

You can check with:

```
$ kubectl -n kube-system get scalingpolicy
```

And the CRD:

```
$ kubectl describe crd scalingpolicies.scalingpolicy.kope.io
```

It should match something like [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/addons/fluentd-gcp/scaler-policy.yaml). You also might considering applying everything from [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/fluentd-gcp)

Comment: The kubectl describe crd scalingpolicies.scalingpolicy.kope.io returns something but the first command kubectl -n kube-system get scalingpolicy says no resources found. I feel like the problem is some kind of version problem because my fluentd is at v3.1.0 but the command is trying to scale v3.0.0. Since I didn't manually install this I am wondering if I should upgrade the cluster to a new version which might fix this.